# Why is tsc complaining on this conditional type?

Tags: typescript

Here is it :

```
type Foo<T, U> = U extends keyof T
    ? T[U] extends { root: string }
    ? T[U]['root'] : never  // not happy here
    : never

type a = Foo<{ k: { root: 'lala' } }, 'k'> // 'lala'  OK
```

Why would the compiler complain even though he's able to return the right type ?

Edit: I have the problem with TS 4.5, with 4.6 and above this does not happen.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5&ssl=7&ssc=8&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFQDRQKoD4oF5NQQAewEAdgCYDOUA1hCHAGZTICwAUFN1APysBtDAF1CJctSgBvKACcEwAFxQqwWQEsyAcygBfTjz6CRAgOTy4wU6OVkIANwiyDPWw6edOoSFACGeWAREGVplGQslKFMAG19Y0z09dFNaUywXAHoMqAA9Xk8OIA)

Comment: I still don't know the reason for the error. But if it helps you, you can try this: type `Foo<T, U> = U extends keyof T ? 'root' extends keyof T[U] ? T[U]['root'] : never : never`

Comment: @caTS It seems to be slightly different problem, mine doesn't happen with TS 4.6+

Comment: A common trick to re-establish constraints that are lost in conditional types is to use `Extract`. In this case: `T[U]['root']` ~> `Extract<T[U], {root: string}>['root']`.